# Nested-Dictionary Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am having an issue with nested dictionaries.

I have a dataframe in which one column ['spikes'], contains a series of nested dictionaries like so:

```
spikes = 
1    {'20230516_1352_E_sorted': {'chan1_1': [25951....
2    {'20230516_1352_E_sorted': {'chan1_1': [28865....
3    {'20230516_1352_E_sorted': {'chan1_1': [32048....
4    {'20230516_1352_E_sorted': {'chan1_1': [35429....
5    {'20230516_1352_E_sorted': {'chan1_1': [38101....
```

Each key starting with `chan1_` contains a list of values.
What I would like is to create a new column for every key starting with `chan1_...` and include the count of values in that list i.e. `chan1_1 = [20, 35, 5, ...]`

I tried doing various versions of:

```
keys_to_count = ['chan1_1', 'chan1_2']

count_values = lambda row: sum(1 for key in keys_to_count if key in row['20230516_1352_E_sorted'])

Trials['count'] = Trials.apply(count_values, axis=1)

print(Trials['count'])
```

but I get `KeyError: '20230516_1352_E_sorted'` which I assume means I am not properly calling the dictionary within a dictionary.

I also tried:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(spikes['20230516_1352_E_sorted'][chan1] for k in spikes for chan1 in spikes['20230516_1352_E_sorted'])
```

and received the same keyerror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address this issue, you can modify your code to access the nested dictionaries correctly.
Example updated, with columns: chan1_1 chan1_2

Example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'spikes': [
    {'20230516_1352_E_sorted': {'chan1_1': [25951]}},
    {'20230516_1352_E_sorted': {'chan1_1': [28865, 31948]}},
    {'20230516_1352_E_sorted': {'chan1_2': [32048]}},
    {'20230516_1352_E_sorted': {'chan1_1': [35429, 38101]}},
    {'20230516_1352_E_sorted': {'chan1_2': [40001, 41001, 42001]}},
]})


def count_values(row, channel):
    """Function to count values in a specific channel"""
    count = 0
    for nested_dict in row['spikes'].values():
        for key, value in nested_dict.items():
            if key == channel:
                count += len(value)
    return count


# Add separate columns for chan1_1 and chan1_2 counts
df['chan1_1'] = df.apply(lambda row: count_values(row, 'chan1_1'), axis=1)
df['chan1_2'] = df.apply(lambda row: count_values(row, 'chan1_2'), axis=1)

# Print the modified DataFrame
print(df)
#                                               spikes  chan1_1  chan1_2
# 0   {'20230516_1352_E_sorted': {'chan1_1': [25951]}}        1        0
# 1  {'20230516_1352_E_sorted': {'chan1_1': [28865,...        2        0
# 2   {'20230516_1352_E_sorted': {'chan1_2': [32048]}}        0        1
# 3  {'20230516_1352_E_sorted': {'chan1_1': [35429,...        2        0
# 4  {'20230516_1352_E_sorted': {'chan1_2': [40001,...        0        3

# Save DataFrame to Excel file
df.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: If I wanted to make separate columns for each chan1_# i.e. chan1_1, chan1_2, how could I add that?

Comment: example updated, with columns: chan1_1  chan1_2